# Activate button, if codebehind has values

Tags: c#, wpf

Can't figure this out. I have got a button that I want disabled until 2 strings in the code behind have got a value. They are set to null initially.

This is my button style xaml at the moment:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF2B2B2B" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF4B4B4B" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid x:Name="Button">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="innerRectangle"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                       Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                              ContentSource="Content"
                                              TextBlock.FontSize="15"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3f3f41" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#007acc" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=saveFolder}" Value="" />
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Source=saveFolder, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True" />
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

And the button it's self:

```
<Button Name="btnGo" Content="Go!" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="btnGo_Click" />
```

Comment: I don't see a trigger setting `IsEnabled` anywhere. Alternatively, you could use a command instead of `Click` and take advantage of `CanExecute`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could control this by setting your button to enabled in a setter, and setting it to disabled using `DataTrigger`s if either property is null:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />

    <!-- Other stuff in style unchanged -->

    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeProperty1}" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeProperty2}" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I'm using the triggers collection on the style rather than the control template because I generally prefer to avoid using the latter unless I need to deal with elements defined within the control template itself.

As BradleyDotNET pointed out in the comments, setting up a command and making use of `CanExecute` is also a fine solution.

Answer (score 1):

If your Button's DataContext is a class implementing some form of property changed event, there is another way you could do this...

In the button's DataContext, create a new bool property for the buttons IsEnabled to be bound to, eg.

```
public bool CanClickButton
{
    get
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstString)
            && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(secondString);
    }
}
```

Then simply add your `RaisePropertyChanged` method for `CanClickButton` to the both string properties' setters, and bind your button's IsEnabled to CanClickButton.

I like doing it this way as I've not yet learnt how to implement commands. For bigger projects, though, I think commands would be a better way to go.